# Multiple consecutive possession

Tags: possessives

What is the correct way of writing **'s** in multiple consecutive possession?

> Bob's dog.
>
> Bob's dog's toy.
>
> Bob's dog's toy's ears.

Is this correct?

Comment: The ears of the toy  I'd call: the ears on the toy. The ears  on Bob's dog's toy.

Comment: Related: [Is it right to say "Jack's father's mother's books"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/322998/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possessive apostrophe for owner of owner of owner of](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188266/possessive-apostrophe-for-owner-of-owner-of-owner-of)

Answer (score 1):

You can have any number of possessives like this: Bob's dog's toy's ears. A very long list would make a sentence awkward, and it is probably a good idea to consider rewriting the sentence if there are more than two consecutive items.